# Empty set in countability proofs

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

It is a provable theorem (defining countable as finite or countably infinite) that a nonempty set $S$ is countable if and only if there exists a surjection $f: \mathbb{N} \to S$ if and only if there exists an injection $g: S \to \mathbb{N}$.

Every single time I have seen the result quoted, it is assumed that $S$ is nonempty. Is this necessary, or is just done to eliminate an extra edge case? The result seems fine to me. If $S = \emptyset$, it's finite, hence countable. Then there is only one map $f: \mathbb{N} \to \emptyset$ -- the empty list -- which is vacuously surjective and injective. (It's surjective since there are no $x \in \emptyset$ we need to map to, and vacuously injective because $f(a) \neq f(b)$ for any $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$.) There is also only one map $g: S \to \mathbb{N}$, once again the empty list, which is again vacuously injective.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

There is certainly an injection (vacuously) from the empty set to any set, so by the usual definition, it is countable. It really should be anyway, because it is finite (in the sense that there is a bijection from the empty set, to a set with a natural number of elements, i.e. itself). There are no maps to the empty set from a nonempty set though, because you need somewhere to send the elements (you would have an "empty map", but the problem is that definitionally, for $f:A\to B$, you need to have that: for each $a\in A$, $\exists!b\in B$ s.t. $(a,b)\in f$).

Answer (score 0):

It's quite reasonable to consider the empty set "countable", and if you leave out the surjection bit in the OP, you can easily get rid of the assumption of nonemptiness:

> A set $S$ is countable iff there is an injection $g: S \to \Bbb{N}$.

But if you let functions have empty images, then the concept of "injection" becomes utterly trivial, because as you note, maps with empty image would be vacuously injective.
For instance, I could get an injection of $\omega_1$, the first uncountable ordinal, into $3 = \{ 0, 1, 2 \}$, by sending all the uncountably many elements of $\omega_1$ to the empty subset $\emptyset \subset 3$.
A definition of "function" that would make $3$ uncountable is obviously going to create way more technical issues than it solves.

In practice, we handle situations where some potential inputs don't get assigned outputs (think of $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$, $f(x) := 1/x$, with the potential input $x = 0$) not by saying, for instance, that

> "$1/0 = \emptyset,$"

but by saying,

> "$x = 0$ is not in the domain of $f(x) = 1/x$"

or,

> "$f(x) = 1/x$ is undefined when $x = 0$."

According to this framework, when we write down a function $f: \Bbb{N} \to \emptyset$, none of the numbers $k \in \Bbb{N}$ are actually in the domain of $f$, i.e. the domain of $f$ is empty, and $f: \emptyset \to \emptyset$ is mundanely revealed as the empty function from the empty set to itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Then there is only one map f:N→∅ -- the empty list -- which is vacuously surjective and injective.

That is *not* the empty list.

The empty function is $g:\emptyset \to \mathbb N$ and that is vacouosly injective and assuredly is *NOT*  surjective.

It is a function as for every $x \in \emptyset$ (of which there are none) it is vacuously true that there is a distinct $y$ so that $f(x) = y$.  And it is injective for any value of $y$ in the image of the mapping, of which there are none, it is vacuously true that there is only one $x \in \emptyset$ so that $f(x) = y$.  But it is *not* surjective as for any $y \in \mathbb N$, of which there are infinitely many, there are *no* $x \in \emptyset$ so that $f(x) = y$.

.....

However a function $f:\mathbb N \to \emptyset$ simply can not exist at all (although it would be vacuously surjective if it existed at all).

To be a function for every $x\in N$, for which there are infinitely many, there must be a distinct $y \in \emptyset$ so that $f(x)=y$ and that is obviously not true.

.....

So the theorem is not true for the empty set; there exists an injective function $f:\emptyset \to \mathbb N$, but there does not exist any function (surjective or otherwise) $g:\mathbb N \to \emptyset$.